# Magento get store url in cms page

Tags: admin, url, cms

I want to get the store URL in cms page when I tried this

```
{{store url='abc/efg/xxx/yyyy'}}
```

It does not return the given URL. Its give output like this

```
http://domain.com
```

but I need to get like this

```
http://domain.com/abc/efg/xxx/yyyy
```

Help to fix this.
I don't know how to **concatenate in CMS page**

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/cms/markup_tags

Refer this

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If the url is determined by a controller and an action you can use this:

```
{{store url="module/controller/action"}}
```

If the url is to a cms page you this:

```
{{store _direct="url-key-here"}}
```

if you want some query params also like `/some-ulr?a=2&b=5` use one of the methods above and add a `_query` parameter.

```
{{store url="module/controller/action" _query="a=2&b=5"}}
{{store _direct="url-key-here" _query="a=2&b=5"}}
```

**[EDIT]**
You can get the same urls in a template file like this:

```
$this->getUrl('module/controller/action'); //for controller pages
$this->getUrl('', array('_direct'=>'some-url-key')); //for cms pages
$this->getUrl('module/controller/action', array('_query'=>'a=2&b=5')); //for query params
$this->getUrl('', array('_direct'=>'some-url-key', '_query'=>'a=2&b=5')); //for query params
```

Comment: how can i get that url in phtml file.use this code `$this->getUrl()`

Comment: @MeenakshiSundaramR. See my edit. It looks better in the answer opposed to a comment.

Answer (score 2):

@Meenakshi,

I had used this

```
<p><a href="{{store url='abc/efg/xxx/yyyy'}}">test</a></p>
```

In cms, and Its working fine for me.

I think you are not getting exact full URL because of hide/show editor issue.
First hide the editor then after put above code in CMS, then It will display as you want.

Answer (score 0):

careful with single quote and double quote, must use double quote

```
{{store url="abc/efg/xxx/yyyy"}}
```