# add Home button in top menu

Tags: menu

I have top menu but i can't put home button in it..

here is code of mu top menu and what i try to do .

```
<?php $_menu = $this->renderCategoriesMenuHtml(0,'level-top') ?>
<?php if($_menu): ?>
<div class="nav-container">
    <ul id="nav">
        <?php echo $_menu ?>
        <li><a title="text1" href="{{store url=''}}"><span>Home</span></a></li>

    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Do I need to enter something in

> store url=''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure that you are editing the right template.
if so change this:

```
<li><a title="text1" href="{{store url=''}}"><span>Home</span></a></li>
```

to This:

```
  <li><a title="text1" href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('')?>"><span><?php echo $this->__('Home');?></span></a></li>
```

There is a chance that the menu is not rendered by the template you are editing. For version 1.7+ the menu is handled differently.
More details on how to add cleanly items to the top menu [can be found here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/7329/146)

Comment: You were right. I have edited out the wrong template.. Thank you very much! :))

Answer (score 1):

```
 1) {{store url=""}}
```

use this only in CMS page.

**To get store url in phtml file**

use the following code

```
$this->getUrl()
```

**To get controller page**

```
$this->getUrl('module/controller/action');
```

**TO get CMS page url**

```
$this->getUrl('', array('_direct'=>'some-url-key')); //for cms pages
```

**To pass parameter in url**

```
$this->getUrl('module/controller/action', array('_query'=>'a=2&b=5')); 
$this->getUrl('', array('_direct'=>'some-url-key', '_query'=>'a=2&b=5'));
```

I have refer [**this**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14443/magento-get-store-url-in-cms-page/14449?noredirect=1#14449) answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i still have problem to show that button in menu.. :/ I tried this '$this->getUrl('', array('_direct'=>'home'));' and this '<li><a href="{{store url='home'}}">home</a></li>' .. but nothing happend..confused...