# Wrong URL returned by WYSIWYG editor for images

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, image, wysiwyg

I've noticed a weird behavior from the WYSIWYG editor in the product description. Whenever I insert an image it will output

```
<img src="{{media url="http://example.com/media/wysiwyg/the-picture.jpg"}}" alt="" />
```

while in another context, such as static blocks editing, it would output

```
<img src="{{media url=wysiwyg/the-picture.jpg"}}" alt="" />
```

This results in displaying

```
<img alt="" src="http://example.com/media/http://example.com/media/wysiwyg/the-picture.jpg">
```

which is obviously not what I want.

I've searched on different topics, and no one seems to have that specific problem. Did anyone come across this, does anyone have a fix?

Comment: have same problem in 1.9.0.1. any solution pls

Comment: i feel your pain here - i have the same issue. shame nobody could give you the answers you were looking for :(

Answer (score 5):

the error is due to `Mage::getBaseUrl('media')` does not pass the store parameter !

To solve this bug, change in :

```
app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Wysiwyg/Images.php
```

Find function : `getImageHtmlDeclaration`

and change :

```
$mediaPath = str_replace(Mage::getBaseUrl('media'), '', $fileurl);
```

by

```
$mediaPath = str_replace(mage::app()->getStore($this->_storeId)->getBaseUrl('media'), '', $fileurl);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the file `Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController` you will see where it add the store url for product wysiwyg.

```
$storeMediaUrl = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);

$content = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/catalog_helper_form_wysiwyg_content', '', array(
    'editor_element_id' => $elementId,
    'store_id'          => $storeId,
    'store_media_url'   => $storeMediaUrl,
));
```

My suggestion for you would be to look into this and debug what exactly is being passed to the config. It might also be worth comparing how this is done in cms pages.

Comment: Thanks for bringing that up, I'll try and have a look at it. Tbh I moved on to something else since then, but +1 for pointing out a specific spot to look up.

Comment: @JulienLachal are you still getting the issue?

Comment: I bet my client does, but I told them how to correct that.

Comment: Any luck with this? I got same issue in Magento 1.9.0.1

Comment: have same problem in 1.9.0.1. any solution pls

Answer (score 1):

Check the following configuration setting: System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Frontend -> Allow Dynamic Media URLs in Products and Categories

Comment: I've checked and it's set to "Yes" already :/

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code.

```
<img src="{{media url="/wysiwyg/the-picture.jpg"}}" alt="" />
```

> the **media url** 'll give the store media url like `http://www.yourdomain.com/media`

to get **Store Url**

```
{{store url=""}}
```

to get **Skin Url**

```
{{skin url=""}}
```

More Details [**Refer this**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14443/magento-get-store-url-in-cms-page/14449?noredirect=1#14449)

Comment: Thank you, but it does not answer my question in any way. My problem is that the url generated by the WYSIWYG editor is wrong, and I'd like it to give me the right URL all the time without having to modify it by hand.