# Wrong media URL in WYSIWYG editor when adding images in various Magento store views

Tags: magento-1.9, image, wysiwyg, media

I will try to explain a strange behavior (maybe bug) when using WYSIWYG editor in Magento 1.9.

**Magento setup**

One website with three store views. Each store view is on different domains. For this case let’s focus only on two storeviews:

storeview 1:  mywebshop.eu
storeview 2:  mywebshop.it

Steps for reproducing the error.

**SCENARIO 1 which is OK.**

1. Open desired product, and open WYSIWYG for description field. Select storeview 1 (english)
2. Add an image (using the editor’s button Insert/Edit image).
3. The Html code I get is ok like this:

> img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/adobe-pdf-icon-02.png"}}" /

The image is corectly displayed in frontend like this:

**SCENARIO 2 which is not OK.**

1. RE-Open the same desired product and open WYSIWYG for description field. (Now select store view 2 (Italian)
2. Add an image (using the editor’s button Insert/Edit image).
3. Now the code I get is like this:

> img src="{{media url="https://mywebshop.it/media/wysiwyg/adobe-pdf-icon-02.png"}}" /

The image in frontend is broken, because the HTML output is like this:

RESULT: the image is not displayed because of malformed img src.

We have recently setup Magento that each store view has a different domain. (Maybe this affects).

I saw very similar question here --> [Wrong URL returned by WYSIWYG editor for images](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16158/wrong-url-returned-by-wysiwyg-editor-for-images)

But this answer doesn't help/work  ([Wrong URL returned by WYSIWYG editor for images](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16158/wrong-url-returned-by-wysiwyg-editor-for-images#answer-111725))

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option - 1

Open or extend (Overwrite) `app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Wysiwyg/Images.php` file and update `getImageHtmlDeclaration` function.

Replace below code

`$mediaPath = str_replace(Mage::getBaseUrl('media'), '', $fileurl);`

To

`$mediaPath = str_replace(mage::app()->getStore($this->_storeId)->getBaseUrl('media'), '', $fileurl);`

Option - 2

`Go to System > Configuration > Content Management (Under General) > WYSIWYG Options`

`Use Static URLs for Media Content in WYSIWYG for Catalog – Select “No”`

I hope it will help you

Comment: I already tried option1, but it doesn't work ... maybe I missing something. Option 2 is not ok beacuse we want to to create a new website in the future and I believe this will create some problems ...

Comment: UPDATE: Option 1 actualy resolves the issue. I just had the the class Mage_Cms_Helper_Wysiwyg_Images extended in another module... Thank you!!

Comment: Please accept answer