# how to use the store url for link in checkoutpage?

Tags: onepage-checkout, ce-1.9.1.0, link

On the checkout page (onepagecheckout) i have included the t&c link. In the contents i included a link to the t&c page like this: `<a href="{{store url="algemene-voorwaarden"}}" target="_blank">algemene voorwaarden</a>` but i does not work... it sends me to: http://dev.blinckstar.nl/checkout/onepage/%7B%7Bstore%20url= ... what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Syntax looks correct.

The URL it generates (`http://dev.blinckstar.nl/checkout/onepage/%7B%7Bstore%20url=`) suggests that it breaks after `url=`. Can you make sure there is absolutely no hidden and broken characters by typing out `"algemene-voorwaarden"` with your keyboard? Do not use copy-paste.

Comment: Siment... i checked and double checked but i am sure it is typed as it should. Hard coding works out fine, but i don't want to use that if possible. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Do get url in phtml file

```
$this->getUrl('module/controller/action'); //for controller pages
$this->getUrl('', array('_direct'=>'some-url-key')); //for cms pages
$this->getUrl('module/controller/action', array('_query'=>'a=2&b=5')); //for query params
$this->getUrl('', array('_direct'=>'some-url-key', '_query'=>'a=2&b=5')); //for query params
```

in cms page

```
{{store url="module/controller/action" _query="a=2&b=5"}}
{{store _direct="url-key-here" _query="a=2&b=5"}}
```

refer [**this**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14443/magento-get-store-url-in-cms-page)

Comment: sorry but i do not quite understand what you mean by this... i am not talking about cms page... i was adding terms & conditions checkbox to the checkout page (admin panel > sales > terms & conditions) and wanted to include a link to the terms and conditions cms page (and 2 other pages) so i used store url="" to do that, but unfortunately it does not do what i expected it to... it might well be that you offer a solution here, but i just don't get it ;(