# Change footer links according to website

Tags: multistore, language, footer

I have 2 websites under same Magento admin: [www.sajidat.com](http://www.sajidat.com) and  [www.tr.sajidat.com](http://www.tr.sajidat.com).

I need to translate the footer links and change its links when I change the store. I mean when I choose `tr.sajidat.com`, I want footer changed to Turkish and change its links to Turkish page. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

For CMS static blocks, pages and widgets:

If you want to edit non-translatable footer links or some banners text, they are mostly located among static blocks. I'll use your block as an example. "footer_links"

Go to CMS->Static blocks.

Look for Footer Links block for the required store language and click to edit.

NOTE: If you have installed a new language and want to duplicate and translate footer links for it, just click Add new block and create the block using the same Identifier (footer_links, for instance) with the required content and specify it to the new store language or store view.

Note:can manage all blocks the same way.

Modify the links the way you like and save the changes:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code in phtml file to get current store URL

```
$this->getUrl('customer/account');
```

In CMS page

```
{{store url="customer/account"}}
```

Refer this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14443/magento-get-store-url-in-cms-page)

Answer (score 0):

In your phtml file, you can check the websiteId

> Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId()